# Selecting overflowing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## Selecting overflowing elements with jQuery

I'm currently doing a project at my internship, and I have stumbled upon an issue which I can't solve myself. I have a horizontal navigation bar, which should support unlimited navigation items. What I want is that all the overflowing navigation items should be hidden in a **view more** button.

**How do I target all the overflowing navigation items?**

### I tried to visualize my idea:

[Link to visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kasiU.png)

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 150px 0 50px;
  background: $secondary;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  @include break(1000px) {
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  li {
    @include break(1000px) {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
  a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 17px 40px;
    background: none;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
    transition: background 0.4s;
    font-family: $font;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    &: hover {
      background: lighten($secondary, 5%);
    }
  }
  .active {
    color: $primary;
    background: lighten($secondary, 5%);
    span {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 5px;
      height: 50px;
      background: $primary;
      @include break(1000px) {
        top: -webkit-calc(100% - 5px);
        top: calc(100% - 5px);
        width: 100%;
        height: 5px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 6</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 7</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 8</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 9</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 10</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 11</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span></span>Item 12</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<!-- .siderbar end -->
```

Comment: you can look at in bootstrap it will help you. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I don't think you ought to be targeting the hidden items - simply toggling the size of the container between the window width and the width of its contents, i.e. all the buttons.

Comment: Sorry, this was an information I should have provided. Bootstrap is not allowed.

Comment: Show some code what you have tried.

Comment: you should try a common dropdown where all other navigation links should be placed

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I have added some code, and tried to visualize my idea. It all have to be dynamic (ie. The number of menu items could vary a lot)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could scroll the contents of the container on "View More...".  Although without code it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Is that your answer for the question?
Please use comment if you have any query or statement.If you have the answer, then you can post it in answer section. Thanks.